# What is a tipping axis?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, terminology

In the figure below for trikes, he mentions about "tipping Axis" and then makes a triangle which is used as a reference for the CG.

My doubt is: what is all this ? I want to understand how that triangle got made.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The axis the bike would rotate around when tipping over.

In the case above they mean the point where the front wheel touches the ground, because that is the fixed point when you pitch over the handlebars in a unwise stop. (Not that this is likely to happen in that configuration, but I saw it happen to more than one friend on BMX bikes growing up.) But they go on to discuss the case of tipping over backward which happens around the point where the real wheels touch the ground.

Comment: How did they come up with the angle of inclination for each of the axes ? Is it trivial to find or otherwise ?

Comment: The diagonal dashed lines in the diagram appear to be 45 degree from the vertical, which means they represent the possible positions for the center of gravity at which the bike would be on the cusp of disaster at one gee horizontal acceleration on a level road. The fact that the pictured CoG is below the line from the front wheel indicates good stability in that direction. The fact that it is above the line from the back wheel indicates some instability to the rear.

Comment: So, is the 45 degree angle a general one which applies for all bikes or is it taken here just for the sake of brevity ?

Comment: It applies equally to all wheeled vehicles. That said the justification for that being the right comparison is not something fit for a comment.

Comment: So, it isn't a general angle then ? And has to be calculated every time for different vehicles ? Is that right ?

Comment: It's a 45 degree angle because they assumed a maximum 1g horizontal force, which equals the 1g downward force. Had they assumed a higher maximum horizontal force, the triangle would be shallower.